# JavaScript to parse json that can be, string, object and array

Tags: javascript, parsing, json

I have to parse a json object that can be a string, array, array of strings and array of object. I realised that it's not good from the beginning that one object can be many types, but I can't change the code from upstream so 
I'll have to deal it in my code instead. I'm building a pixel library for modern browser so I'm not using jQuery or lodash. I'm supporting most modern browser and IE >= 9

Here's the example of the data that can be returned

```
"author": {
 "@type": "Person",
 "name": "Author"
}
```

Or

```
"author":[{"@type":"Person","name":"Author"}]
```

Or

```
"author": 'Author'
```

Or

```
"author": ['Author', 'Author1']
```

And this is my code.

```
  let obj = {};
  try {
    const json = document.querySelector('div.json');
    if (json) {
      let disc = JSON.parse(json.innerHTML);
      let authors = disc.author;

      if (typeof authors !== 'undefined' && Array.isArray(authors) && authors.length > 0) {
        authors = authors.map((author) => {
          if (typeof author === 'object' && author.name) {
            return author.name;
          } else {
            return author;
          }
        });
      }

      if (typeof authors !== 'undefined' && !Array.isArray(authors) && typeof authors === 'object') {
        authors = [authors.name];
      }

      if (typeof authors !== 'undefined' && typeof authors === 'string') {
        authors = authors.split(',');
      }

      obj.cAu: authors.join(',');
    }
  } catch (e) { }

  return obj;
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: Could you include the content "div.json" has in your html. We need to have your sample json to be able to review your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would have written the function as below.
One thing that stood out that I noticed is that you are not returning anything in the catch statement of your try. So there is a certain 'ambiguity' as to what the function will return.

Here is my reasoning for the code style below:

1. I expect the invoker to provide me with the JSON string that needs to data extracted from it, so that I can perform some immediate input validation. If the input is falsey I will return an empty string.
2. I check whether the parsed result is an instance of an array (undefined or null will not pass this check)
3. If it is an instance of an array I will check whether it is an array of objects, otherwise I will assume it is a string. I map these entries, and join them with a comma and return the result
4. if the type is of an object (and not array since we already checked for that), I will return the name property of that object.

Feel free to wrap this in a try'catch but make sure you return something on the catch. I assume the invoker is expecting a string back.

```
function parseAuthor(authorString){
  if(!authorString){
    return '';
  }

  const authorObj = JSON.parse(authorString);

  if (typeof authorObj === 'string') {
    return authorObj;
  }

  if (authorObj instanceof Array) {
    entries = authorObj.map((a) => {
      if(typeof a === 'object' && a.name){
        return a.name;
      } else {
        return a;
      }
    });

    return entries.join(',');
  }

  if (typeof authorObj === 'object' && authorObj.name) {
    return authorObj.name;
  }

  return '';
}
```